# How can I correlate a RSSI value to a distance measurement more efficiently?

Tags: communication, measurement, matlab, statistics

I want to develop a trilateration algorithm using 3 fixed advertising beacons in different parts of a room and a mobile receiver which  continuously gets the RSSI values of the 3 fixed beacons and transmits them to a laptop running a MATLAB program which processes the data.
The problem is that I want to plot the location of the mobile beacon in real time and I need a solution which needs to "linearize" the RSSI values to a distance (preferably in meters). I am currently using this basic function for this, but the slightest amount of noise messes up my trilateration and places the mobile receiver outside of my map in MATLAB:

```
function distance = rssiToDistance(rssi, referenceRssi, referenceDistance, pathLossExponent)
    if rssi <= 0
        distance = referenceDistance * 10^((referenceRssi - rssi) / (10 * pathLossExponent));
    else
        distance = NaN;
    end
end
```

Experimentally, the RSSI at 1m is about -50dBm with a path loss exponent of 2, so I have used these values in the function above, but with no good.
I should also mention that the frequency of the devices is 2.4GHz.
What steps could I approach?

Comment: So what does your actual data look like? Is there a good correlation between RSSI and distance?

Comment: Well I just placed the 3 advertising beacons and the receiver in a straight line, with the beacons distanced at 1m between themselves and the receiver, and I sampled 929 measurements of RSSIs,
the average for the one at 1m from the receiver is -63.7201 dBm, with a std of 0.5141, the average for the one at 2m is -67.1012 dBm with a std of 0.3419 and for the one at 3m it's -70.6663, with a std of 0.7285.

Comment: What about other positions of the receiver? You need to take data that is representative of your actual application's operating conditions. I suspect that you are going to find that the data do not fit a smooth curve as the result of nonlinear effects such as interference from the beacon signals reflecting from nearby objects. Also, the transmitter and receiver antennas may not be as omnidirectional as you think they are.

Comment: afaik, nobody who's tried this, yours truly included, has ever gotten a satisfactory result.

Comment: I can clearly see that now, I individually placed each beacon in line of sight with the receiver at 10cm, 20cm, all the way to 300cm and sampled 50 RSSI values each time. I averaged the values and got the values below, which do not seem linear at all:
-52.3791 -51.8693 -53.1765 -55.7255 -56.7124 -58.8562 -58.0523 -55.7582 -57.6013 -59.0915 -58.5163 -63.6601 -64.5556 -56.9346 -58.6405 -66.9804 -64.6863 -63.6013 -63.4183 -60.9608 -61.6863 -65.3791 -71.4510 -65.4641 -62.0588 -59.0392 -60.2222 -61.4837 -68.3922 -70.3203
I will have to work hard even to obtain a 1m accuracy, but I will still try.